# Will creating a Closed Testing Channel list my app on the app store?

Tags: android, mobile, google-play

I am developing a new app and would like to create a 'Closed Testing' channel in the Play Store. However I do not want this app to be publicly listed/searchable on the Play Store yet (once it has gone through testing I would like it published).

When I create the Closed Testing channel, will the app be visible for everyone/searchable on the Play Store?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. They Play Store URL for your app will just show an error page for all users who are not in the closed test. As long as you don't publish it in the release or open test your app won't be visible.

Please note that once you upload an app, the signig key store and application ID are set. You will not be able to change them afterwards unless you create a new play store entry with a new application ID.

(To be more specific: You can change the signing key but you will still need the original key for the change process)